# Problem creating feature layer with synchronized edits on both ArcGIS Online and ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I am working on a project where I have created a shapefile of building footprints on ArcMap 10.4, and I need the features and their attribute tables to be editable inside of ArcGIS Online for those using it in the organization. I also need the edits to transfer over to ArcMap. I have the data stored in the organization's Server, but I have not been able to export the data into ArcGIS Online with editing and have the changes made in AGOL transfer over to the shapefile in ArcMap successfully.

If anyone knows a good way to make this possible, that would be fantastic. I apologize if this is very simple as I am new to the industry.

Comment: Everything in the help. Bring feature service to arcmap table of contents. Right click, create local copy for editing etc.

Comment: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/manage-data/editing-fundamentals/making-a-local-copy-of-a-service-for-editing.htm

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I think you guys are both right. The only problem is that when I attempt to create a local copy on the feature service, every time it crashes ArcMap. I'm not sure if it's just a problem with ArcMap, or if I am not using the correct data/method.